# How to return JSON response from soap based web service.

Tags: web-services, cxf

SOAP based web service is implemented in Apache CXF JAX WS and returns xml based response. I have one JavaScript client for which I want to return JSON from this service.

Comment: Potential useful reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140299/why-not-soap-with-json Long story short, it's not SOAP anymore.

Comment: Thanks. This really helped!!

Answer (score 0):

As CollinD commented, my answer to the (now deleted) question https://stackoverflow.com/a/9140399/155689 would work.

Just include the JSON inside the body of a Soap response by wrapping it with CDATA tags. Inside CXF you could stringify, even encode the json if you want to (in case, for some weird reason the JSON payload might include a CDATA tag or similar).

How the javascript client reads the SOAP response depends on the JS framework but if that is already taken care of then it just needs to (optionally) decode the body payload and load as JSON as normal.